# Scroll nestedscrollview to bottom of textView

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I have some `editText` in my activity so put them into `nestedScrollView` and my activity has the `adjustResize` attribute.
I put a textView at bottom of each editText to show the exitText input error.
But their `visibility` are `Gone`.
When the soft-keyboard open I don't have a problem whit the first `exitText`, when I click on `Next` button of the soft-jetboard `nestedScrollView` scrolled to the bottom of next `editText` and if user write a wrong input to my `editText` the `textView` of them will be visible and show the error of input to the user.

***BUT PROBLEM IS***.

They are below of their `editText`.
How I can scroll `nestedScrollView` to the bottom of the `textView`?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `TextInputEditText` and `TextInputLayout` instead of `EditText` and `TextView`.

The scrolling behavior will be managed by Android's system and should result correctly.

Also, it will simplify your code:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hint"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

You can set and remove errors with:

**Java**

```
text_input_layout.setError("Error message");
text_input_layout.setError(null);
```

**Kotlin**

```
text_input_layout.error = "Error message"
text_input_layout.error = null
```